# Returning next highest value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have in cells B2 to J2 the following values:

```
     B     C     D     E    F    G    H    I    J
2   100%, 100%, 100%, 80%, 80%, 80%, 50%, 50%, 50%
```

I want to return the next highest value that is less than `B2` i.e. 80%

Answer (score 0):

You could use this formula:

```
=SMALL(B2:J2,RANK.EQ(B2,B2:J2,1)-1)
```

[image]

You may want to combine with `IFERROR` to prevent the `#NUM!` results. Note I believe that `RANK.EQ` is only available since Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=LARGE(range, number)`

EG

```
=LARGE(A1:E1,2)
```

This would get the 2nd largest, where as  `=LARGE(A1:E1,3)` would return the 3rd largest.

It will ignore the order of the numbers which may not be ideal as you do state 2nd largest after the value in `B2`. This would mean if your values were in this order (B2 - J2)

100 100 100 75 75 150 50 50

Then the answer would be 100 as it's the second biggest, where as I guess you'd want the answer to be 75. However, as this suggestion may suffice I'll leave it as an answer!

As an aside, the same concept always works with `=SMALL(A2:A6, 2)`